# Starting from the nth term to the end of list python

Tags: python, list

Hello I was wondering how you could do the following in python

Suppose we have these lists

```
["Apples","Pears","Oranges","Grapes"]
["Apples","Pears","Oranges","Grapes","Strawberries"]
["Apples","Pears","Oranges","Pumpkins","Cherries","Lemons"]
```

And I wanted to extract to extract the 4th element and beyond. So...

```
["Grapes"]
["Grapes","Strawberries"]
["Pumpkins","Cherries","Lemons"]
```

The lists will all have more than 3 elements.

How would I do this?

Comment: [Slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/4996248) the lists.

Comment: Use `My_list[3:]`

Comment: are all the lists in the example given, different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fruits = ["Apples","Pears","Oranges","Pumpkins","Cherries","Lemons"]
print(fruits[3:])
```

Comment: Lack of explanation on this subject. Please complete the answer.